# EF Code First Database migration error on second start

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I have a web application with local database in production environment. In new build I decided to change database and added database migration.
I ran **Enable-Migrations** in NuGet console.
Program has generated 201410141412423_InitialCreate.cs file as I already had database - there're some code that initialize my database schema.
Then I added one field in model Workstation

```
public class Workstation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastCall { get; set; } //this field was added

    public string UserConfiguration { get; set; }

    private readonly ICollection<StatusBase> _statuses = new Collection<StatusBase>();

    public virtual ICollection<StatusBase> Statuses
    {
        get { return _statuses; }
    }
}
```

I ran **Add-Migration WorkstationLastCallAdded** command in NuGet console. New file with migration logic was generated with next code:

```
public partial class WorkstationLastCallAdded : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Workstations", "LastCall", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Workstations", "LastCall");
    }
}
```

I also added next code in Global.asax file to update my database

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppDbContext, MigrationConfiguration>()); 
}
```

Then I build it and run, and everything works fine.
When I deploy new build to server, there's a database file with some data on the server. The database has old scheme - without LastCall field. So I expect migration updates my database and I won't loose any data.
When I run my site after deploy - everything works fine. Data is not lost and database is updated correctly.
If I restart server or IIS and run my site again - I've got an error.

*Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.*

When I open local db and watch _MigrationHistory table - there're two rows with *1410151540264_InitialCreate* and *201410141956597_WorkstationLastCallAdded* migration id's.

Could anybody help me please? Any ideas what's going wrong? Why it works correctly on first run after update but fails on the second?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, the answer it pretty simple. You have two migrations:

```
201410151540264_InitialCreate
201410141956597_WorkstationLastCallAdded
```

You *InitialCreate* miration is **newer** than *WorkstationLastCallAdded* migration. Why? Because *InitialCreate* is implicitly added to *_MigrationHistory* table when your DB is created for the first time and you have no migrations. The timestamp for *InitialCreate* in this case is, of course, equal to current server time. *WorkstationLastCallAdded*, on the other hand, has a fixed timestamp which reflects the time when you ran `Add-Migration WorkstationLastCallAdded` command. Therefore, if you create a database **after** you've created *WorkstationLastCallAdded*, *InitialCreate* will be the 'newest' migration.

What happens next? Db initializer searches for the newest migration and finds *InitialCreate*. Then it compares *InitialCreate* model hash with current model hash and sees that these hashes are different (of course they are, you have changed your model!). And then you got your error.

The easiest way to solve this is to rename your *WorkstationLastCallAdded* timestamp (in migration designer file) to something like this:

```
99999999999999_0001_WorkstationLastCallAdded
```

A bunch of nines ensures that this migration is older than *InitialCreate*. `0001` reflects the order of migration. If you want to create another migration, you should name it like this:

```
99999999999999_0002_SomeOtherFieldAdded
```

Hope this helps!